# DNA to Protein Python Function

Tags: python, function

I'm a huge Python noobie trying to finish my code of translating DNA to RNA to amino acid - it should start printing proteins once the 'Met' protein is found, and stop printing once the 'STOP' proteins are found, and I want it to return a list. But somehow it ONLY prints Met when this DNA string is included? I wonder where I'm going wrong...

edit: thank you!

Comment: The formatting of your posted code seems off. Can you update it, for indentation and to be a complete running example? That's the best way to get help with your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(protein_start, sequence_num, 3):
    codon = codon_list[rna[i:i+3]]
    if (codon == "STOP"):
        return protein // or a break statement if more code
    else:
        protein.append(codon)
```

Answer (score 0):

You only print when it is condon == 'Met', you can do a small cheat and just and a check statment.

```
passed_Met = false
for i in range(protein_start, sequence_num, 3):
    codon = codon_list[rna[i:i+3]]
    if (codon == "STOP"):
        return protein // Returns the proten when 'STOP' is found

    elif (passed_Met):
        protein.append(codon)

    elif (codon == "Met"):
        protein.append(codon)
        passed_Met = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main missing part here is in the end you need to convert your elif statement to an else statement which covers all other aminoacids. In your current code you only append when there is a Met in the sequence.

In your first function you might want to change:

```
def transcribe(str):

    dna = 'ATGC'
    rna = 'UACG'
    transcription = str.maketrans(dna, rna)
    return (str.translate(transcription))
```

and as a second point you may also want to change

```
rna = translate(dna) to rna = transcribe(dna)
```